# Rails 5 - How to update parent object when child object is modified

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I have a situation where Orders are made up of one or more Order Items. Order Items have (among other things) item_price and quantity fields. Orders, in turn, have subtotal, shipping, tax, and total fields. What I'd like to do is to recalculate the Order subtotal and total values whenever an associated Order Item is created, updated, or deleted.

I have attempted to use :after_save and :after_destroy callbacks in the OrderItem model from which I update the parent object. I have also attempted to update the parent object from the OrderItemsController in the given action (create, updated, destroy), like in the code below. But it seems that the given OrderItem that is being edited persists. Looking at the output in the log files, it looks like COMMIT on the database occurs after the callback is called or at the very end of the controller action execution.

I have also attempted to reload the Order object and save it.

```
  def update
    if @order_item.update(order_item_params)
      @order_item.save
      @order_item.order.reload
      @order_item.order.save
      redirect_to @order_item.order, notice: 'Order item was successfully updated.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

I have solutions in mind that involve setting a 'needs_update' boolean value on the Order object and recalculating the required values when the object is needed again. But that seems like an ugly solution. I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: Have you tried using "touch" in the relationship in your order_item model?